# Indexing of dictionaries in list

Tags: python, json

I'm new to Python and I am currently trying to work with JSON files in Python. My JSON file looks as follows (please ignore the content):

```
    [{
  "Id" : "5444",
  "date" : "2012-02-01",
  "data" : [ {
    "Name" : "Fred Smith",
    "Sex" : "Male",
    "description" : "{\"car\": \"Suzuki\", \"salary\": 100000, \"married\": null}"
  }, {
    "occupation" : "smith",
    "City" : "New York",
    "data" : "{\"height\": \"6ft\", \"GMATscores\": [{\"verbal\": \"None\", \"reasoning\": 200, \"numerical\": 0.0}]}"
  } ]
} ]
```

I have been struggling for hours, how do I extract the value for "reasoning: 200" out of this mess?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `json` standard library module? Can you show us what *code you wrote* during the hours you were struggling?

Comment: json.loads(a[0]['data'][1]['data'])['GMATscores'][0]['reasoning'**

Answer (score 1):

you can use [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module:

```
import json 



my_json = [{
  "Id" : "5444",
  "date" : "2012-02-01",
  "data" : [ {
    "Name" : "Fred Smith",
    "Sex" : "Male",
    "description" : "{\"car\": \"Suzuki\", \"salary\": 100000, \"married\": null}"
  }, {
    "occupation" : "smith",
    "City" : "New York",
    "data" : "{\"height\": \"6ft\", \"GMATscores\": [{\"verbal\": \"None\", \"reasoning\": 200, \"numerical\": 0.0}]}"
  } ]
} ]

inner_json = json.loads(my_json[0]['data'][1]['data'])

# {'height': '6ft',
# 'GMATscores': [{'verbal': 'None', 'reasoning': 200, 'numerical': 0.0}]}

inner_json['GMATscores'][0]['reasoning']
# 200
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON data you added here is not really clean. It's a mix of json and escaped string value. The data inside your second 'data' key is a string, so that needs to be json.loaded first.

```
json1 = [{
  "Id" : "5444",
  "date" : "2012-02-01",
  "data" : [ {
    "Name" : "Fred Smith",
    "Sex" : "Male",
    "description" : "{\"car\": \"Suzuki\", \"salary\": 100000, \"married\": null}"
  }, {
    "occupation" : "smith",
    "City" : "New York",
    "data" : "{\"height\": \"6ft\", \"GMATscores\": [{\"verbal\": \"None\", \"reasoning\": 200, \"numerical\": 0.0}]}"
  } ]
} ]


json2 = json.loads(j[0]['data'][1]['data'])

print(json2['GMATscores'][0]['reasoning'])
```